# iOS SE: What happens when I use Emoji's?

Tags: support, unicode, emoji

I can post [ ✨😜✨] emojis in an SE question from the iOS App.

[image]

**What is the result for users without the emoji character set?**

Comment: From the app my [✨✨] emojis remain visible.

Comment: 

Comment: 

Comment: @nicael great, [you broke the app](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QZSkc.png)!!

Comment: @Sha (YEP!!!!) But... wait, are you *sure* that it is me?

Comment: @nicael pretty sure, other questions load just fine.

Comment: @Sha This is... this must be celebrated! And you don't see my comments? My beautiful forest? Flowers? Food? And you are using iPhone 4S?

Comment: @nicael using iPhone 4S mobile app yes, no flowers for me.

Comment: @Sha And the forest?? Do you see the forest??? :D

Comment: @nicael [this is what I see in desktop Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wFCoK.png)

Comment: Strange, some trees are missing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XsguG.png

Comment: @nicael if you can recreate it there, it might be an important step in fixing a bug that could seriously get out of hand

Comment:            

Comment: @nicael will you please reproduce that exact forest comment [in this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234499/comments-with-many-emojis-breaks-the-ios-app-when-viewed) for debugging purposes.

Comment: Emojis are actually default on all Apple products, so anyone with an Apple product can type them anywhere. And therefore see them if they're from someone else. It'll depend on whether you're using a system that has unicode Emojis installed.

Answer (score 4):

This is the result:

> [image]

(blank squares)

Comment: Lol, I see them ))

Comment: Windows and Ubuntu probably lack support. Since emojis became so popular with iPhone, I bet Mac added support so that their cloud sharing of notes and docs wouldn't look bad.

Comment: @jt0dd true, and everyone can download the font if they want, but it's not available by default.

Comment: *Ahem*, windows and ububntu don't count :D

Comment: @jt0dd *Ahem*, W3C doesn't count  :D

Comment: @jt0dd,       ' : Chrome doesn't show those emoji on my Mac (yay!), but Firefox and Safari on the same machine do (meh). (This *might* be related to a browser's [preference for a specific font type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884177/how-can-i-determine-what-font-a-browser-is-actually-using-to-render-some-text/20830300#20830300), like Apple Advanced Technology, Microsoft OpenType or OpenType PostScript.)

Comment: Is this still an issue?  I've been linked to this 4-year-old post as evidence that emoji shouldn't be used. I thought only legacy systems still had this problem.

Comment: @RubelliteFae totally, I see squares in your comment even on my mobile device. (LG4) So all in all, emojis will never be supported fully, each OS will have its own set.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That is very odd. Emojipedia—which is admittedly not a great source for correct info, but at least they have *complete* info—says that LG3 and new all have support ( https://emojipedia.org/lg/ ). I'm surprised to hear that Unicode will never be fully supported. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I see them (Mac, Safari 7):

> [image]

Comment: Yikes, I added a line break. I didn't notice because of the app, but I'm sure the formatting gods got a little angry..

Comment: @jt0dd Ok, I am retaking screenshot.

Comment: Now we have 3 level answer :D [[[Question screenshoted] Question screenshoted] answer]

Comment: Now if you go take the screen-shot of your Mac screen-shot from Windows and explain the difference between platform support, you'll have a pretty cool 4 level answer.

Comment: I see it all using Safari on iPhone as well.

Comment: What is this, jt0ddception?

Comment: @rub wat? Unsure wat do you spek of

Comment: Ah ok, got it lol