# Emoji might be overwhelming the app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, emoji

When trying to view [iOS SE: What happens when I use Emoji's?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234490/ios-se-what-happens-when-i-use-emojis) via the iOS app, I get this:

> [image]

It's consistent, retrying does not help and the request always fail.

All other questions load just fine, so I highly suspect the cause is the Emoji icons used in there, especially in the comments that contain lots of them.

Beta channel, version 1.0.1.85

**Update**: still happening in 1.0.1.88 and I also found that the "preview" seen for example in tag search shows the Emoji just fine:

> [image]

Comment: 

Comment: Lol. 

Comment: Now you can't view this question from iOS App. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an API issue that was fixed sometime ago by Kevin Montrose.