# Comments with specific emoji combination breaks the iOS App when viewed

Tags: bug, ios-app, emoji

A comment with many emojis breaks the iOS App [blank screen & Request Failed] when viewed. [See this question about emojis with the App for a working example.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234490/ios-se-what-happens-when-i-use-emojis?noredirect=1#comment771008_234490) I'll attempt to recreate the scenario in this question.

Done. **This question can no longer be viewed from the iOS app.**

---

In the comments below, a user posts 2 comments with emojis:

- The first emoji comment includes spacing that avoids certain breaking of specific emojis. **This case does not break the app.**
- The second emoji comment does not include these spaces, and results in unusual behavior, while **breaking the iOS app**:

[image]

The difference is likely the key to figuring out the bug.

Comment: ‌​           

Comment: I put space so all trees are visible: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vL4zf.png

Comment: 